# YiiBooster :: bootbox \ bootbox.modal() does not generate .modal-dialog and .modal-content divs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, twitter-bootstrap-2, yii-booster, bootbox

I need this TbButton to open a modal with some HTML content (an iframe with a youtube video):

```
<?php
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
    array(
        'label' => Yii::t('xxx', 'xxx'),
        'type' => 'info',
        'size' => 'mini',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'onclick' => 'js:bootbox.modal(
                "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"480\" src=\"' . GxHtml::encode($model->video_url) . '\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                "Some title"
            );'
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

I expect it to create something like this:

```
<div class="bootbox modal fade bootbox-alert in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" style="margin-top: -10px;">×</button>
                <div class="bootbox-body">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-bb-handler="ok" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But instead it generates just this:

```
<div class="bootbox modal fade in" tabindex="-1" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="close">×</a>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Since .modal-dialog and .modal-content divs are missing, the modal "container" does not show up: only its contents do (on transparent background). What should I add to the code so that it create the container classes?

Comment: show the php code for rendering modal.

Comment: In my example the modal gets rendered by javascript, not PHP, through the TbButton's onClick event (using the modal() function included in YiiBooster's bootbox):

'onclick' => 'js:bootbox.modal(
                "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"480\" src=\"' . GxHtml::encode($model->video_url) . '\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                "Some title"
            );'

Comment: Thanks, @RafayZiaMir, for your help. I just tried with the simplest `bootbox.alert("Hello world!");`, but it does not create .modal-dialog and .modal-content divs either:

`<div class="bootbox modal fade in" tabindex="-1" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-body">Hello world!</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><a data-handler="0" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:;">OK</a></div>
</div>`